# Valid Canadian Visitor Visa in my old passport with a removed machine readable zone

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passports, canada

I want to travel in Canada on November but I renewed my passport. When I renewed my passport, the machine readable zone in my old passport was cut in order to make it useless. Also my visa is intact.

My question is can I travel in Canada with both my passport although my old passport can not be read with a machine? The Old passport should be intact?

Comment: No it's different.My question is if my old passport should be intact or doesn't matter only the visa need to be intact?

Comment: Not sure about entering Canada but to enter the UK the machine readable zone does not need to be intact on the expired passport. The Visa is still valid and the Immigration Officer will manually enter the expired passport's number and then use that to validate the biometrics (prints of thumb & index finger of right hand). Perhaps someone can confirm if it's the same for Canada?

Comment: It is normal for countries to cut or place holes in expired passports. But they should not damage the visas. As long as the visa is undamaged you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you have a new and old passport it is fine,

From an email with the Canadian High Comission:

> If you have a valid visa for Canada in your full/expired passport, and you have been issued a new passport, you may continue to use the visa, but you will need to travel with both your new passport and the full/expired passport which contains the valid visa when you travel to Canada.